# Constant row-column sum matrices?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, matrices, enumerative-combinatorics

1. Given an integer $T$ how many $n\times n$ matrices in $\mathbb Z_{\geq0}^{n\times n}$ we have such that every row and column sum to same $T$?
2. Do the set of constant row and column sum matrices form any kind of algebraic structure (it is definitely definable by linear equations) by which I mean closedness, more than permutation invariance at least for special classes etc.)?

Comment: These are the lattice points in the $T$th dilate of the Birkhoff polytope. Look up the “Anand-Dumir-Gupta conjecture.”

Comment: The set is obviously closed under addition, and not-quite-so-obviously closed under multiplication, also under multiplication by integer scalars. Every element can be written as an integer linear combination of $n^2-2n+2$ or fewer permutation matrices.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Could you please explain closedness under multiplication of matrices? It seems to admit stromg algebraic structures then.

Comment: As mentioned by  Gerry Myerson, the set forms a semigroup under addition. The semigroup algebra over a field is Cohen-Macaulay, which has some interesting consequences.

Comment: @RichardStanley 1. Is there a simple reference for CM property for semigroup algebra over a field and has it been studied in this scenario? 2. Gerry Myerson also says 'not-quite-so-obviously closed under multiplication, also under multiplication by integer scalars' which seems to imply closed under matrix multiplication perhaps or some other multiplication?

Comment: @Turbo: here's a nice survey-ish paper- http://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/wbruns/brunsw/pdf-article/1-BRUNS.pdf

Comment: @SamHopkins I see it closed for $2\times2$ under multiplication.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I do not see closedness under $\times$. Do the $n^2-2n+2$ permutation matrices form a closed set under $\times$ operation?

Comment: Ha, I just finished posting a proof of closure under matrix multiplication. Note that it's not a fixed $n^2-2n+2$ permutation matrices, but a different set for different constant line-sum matrices.

Comment: The closed under multiplication property is not very related to the commutative algebra/Ehrhart theory stuff, as far as I know.

Comment: The row sums of an $n\times n$ matrix are equal if and only if the all 1's column vector is a right eigenvector. Similarly for equal column sums and the all 1's row vector being a left eigenvector. Hence these properties are preserved under product assuming the row and column sums are not 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple formula, you are out of luck except for small $n$ or $T$. As Sam mentions in a comment, these are the integer points in a dilated Birkhoff polytope. Since the vertices of the polytope are lattice points, the number of matrices is a polynomial of degree $(n-1)^2$ in $T$ for any fixed $n$ (the Ehrhart polynomial) but the polynomial is only known up to $n=9$.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0703600.pdf) and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.2422.pdf) have some stuff about asymptotics.  Searching for these buzzwords will get you more interesting things, like [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10801-008-0155-y.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I commented there's closure under (matrix) multiplication, and OP asked for an explanation, so here goes.

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ constant line-sum matrices with constants $a,b$, respectively.

Let $A$ have rows $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n$, let $B$ have columns $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n$, let $C=AB$, and let $\underline b$ be the column $n$-vector $$\pmatrix{b\cr b\cr\vdots\cr b\cr}$$

Then the entries of the first row of $C$ are the dot products $r_1\cdot c_1,r_1\cdot c_2,\dots,r_1\cdot c_n$. So, the sum of the entries of the first row of $C$ is $$r_1\cdot(c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_n)=r_1\cdot\underline{b}=ab$$

The same argument applies to each row of $C$, and a similar argument applies to each column of $C$, so $C$ is a constant line-sum matrix with constant $ab$.

Comment: Thank you very much.